# How to troubleshoot a slowly leaking toilet cistern/tank

Tags: leak, toilet, troubleshooting

One of my toilets is slowly leaking. It has (what I have deduced from Google) a dual push button cistern and a float-cup fill valve. Here's a photo.

[image: Image of toilet hardware]

As you can see, from this animated GIF sped up 60x, it slowly drains and then fills every 20 minutes or so.

[image: Movie of slowly decreasing water level]

##### How can a troubleshoot the issues here?

I suspect I could just order a replacement on Amazon, but since I don't have a good framework for how to troubleshoot, I may be missing a stupidly easy fix requiring nothing.

I have access to basic tools.

Comment: try cleaning the rubber gasket just above the tank bottom, it could have build-up which prevents a good seal. Adding vaseline can help complete marginal seals, but it also can degrade some rubber seals, making that more of a stop-gap than a true fix.

Comment: You can also just get a new flush kit, they aren't that expensive, even a fancy 2-button oem replacement one should be well under $50.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the response. I've felt around the gasket, and there doesn't seem to be any significant buildup. But it does seem surprisingly stiff for something that's supposed to be water tight. I'll try the vaseline trick.

Comment: @dandavis months later, someone upvoted which reminded me of this question. I ended up replacing all of the kit with one I ordered on Amazon. Hardest part was making sure the size was right. Happy to upvote and accept an answer if you want to write one.

Answer (score 0):

The Glacier Bay brand is from Homedepot. They should have the kit to do the replacement of the flush seal.  Operative term here is "should" I have heard from others that those dual flush toilets were impossible to find parts for.
Good luck, may you be successful in your search.